# StringEntity/string to HttpEntity

Tags: android, json, httpentity

I'm using the loopj library (https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) and it's recently changed to be compatible with API 23.

When submitting a 'put' request I would pass the `StringEntity` into the put method like so:

```
client.put(CallApplication.getContext(),url, request.StringEntity, responseHandler);
```

My `StringEntity` is an object that's converted into Json by doing:

```
public static StringEntity getJsonFromObject(Object object) {

    String json = new Gson().toJson(object);
    StringEntity stringEntity = null;
    try {
        stringEntity = new StringEntity(json, HTTP.UTF_8);
        stringEntity.setContentType("text/json");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return stringEntity;
}
```

Now I need to use `HttpEntity` instead and it's not clear how I can get it. How can I get my json string into the `HttpEntity`?

Comment: have u tried with urlencodedfromentity method which takes name value pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens there is a

```
cz.msebera.android.httpclient.entity.StringEntity
```

available to use. Who knew!

Cheers anyway

Answer (score 0):

> You can add namevalue pair to set entity

ArrayList nvp= new ArrayList();
nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keyname", jsonvalue));

client.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));

Comment: setEntity method doesnt exist

Comment: public RequestHandle get(Context context, String url, HttpEntity entity, String contentType, ResponseHandlerInterface responseHandler) {
        return sendRequest(httpClient, httpContext, addEntityToRequestBase(new HttpGet(URI.create(url).normalize()), entity), contentType, responseHandler, context);
    }   your client contain this method can you try to call this

Comment: create seperate object of Httpentity